# Why does this not return anything when searching for a class that is there?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the "Next change Id" off of the html from [here](https://poe.ninja/stats) and I am using the module Beautifulsoup4 to do so. The next change id seems to be under the stats-overview class so I tried searching for it and it just returns an empty list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ninja = requests.get("https://poe.ninja/stats")

soup = BeautifulSoup(ninja.content, "html.parser")
stats_overview = soup.find_all("div", class_="stats-overview")
print(stats_overview) # --> prints '[]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website is loaded via `JavaScript`, `requests` module will not be able to render `JS` on the fly.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://poe.ninja/stats")

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/8609dfa5ae9de8b229899c06ba6a5c29/Data.csv)

[image]

Or Call the back-end `API` directly via:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests



r = requests.get("https://poe.ninja/api/Data/GetStats")
df = pd.read_json(r.text, orient="index")

df.to_csv("data.csv", header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Network` tab you will get following `API` which returns data in `json` format.

> https://poe.ninja/api/Data/GetStats

```
import requests

r=requests.get("https://poe.ninja/api/Data/GetStats").json()
print(r['next_change_id'])
print(r['stash_tabs_processed'])
print(r['api_bytes_downloaded'])
print(r['character_bytes_downloaded'])
print(r['ladder_bytes_downloaded'])
print(r['pob_characters_calculated'])
```

Comment: :P have you reviewed my the end of my answer :P

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη : nope.Sorry mate.I just saw selenium option.